# After selecting "shut down" (and not "Update and shut down"), Windows 10 did install some updates. How to prevent that?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, updates

After selecting "shut down" (and not "Update and shut down"), Windows 10 did install some updates. How to prevent that?

[image]

When the computer shut down:

[image]

When I started the computer:

[image]

I use Windows 10 x64 1607. The Windows update service was disabled.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you clicked **Shut down** and _not_ **Update and shut down**? If so, you can try [this link](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/force-full-shutdown-fully-reinitialize-windows-8).

Comment: Wonder what happens if you do a forceful shutdown via elevated command prompt such as . . . . . . . `shutdown -r -f -t 01` just omit the `-r` if you wish to **not** "*restart*" and just shutdown.

Comment: use hibernation to "shutdown" Windows to avoid this when you are in hurry and want to "shut down" windows

Comment: Which update wasn't installed?  If it was a feature update, feature updates, are not installed upon shutdown on purpose.  Edit your question.  Can anyone find the duplicate to this question that was asked sometime last year?